# find number of duplicated lines based on match repeated condition

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep, regular-expression

Basically i do have a large text file on linux server and i would like to count duplicate for entries based on first 6 digits only:

**Input:**

```
1111110000000222982
112114
1111119292828
11101110
112114
```

**Output:**

```
111111 (2)
112114 (2)
```

> what is the best solution to handle that case?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest take a look if you available.

Comment: `cat file | awk '{ print substr($0, 0, 6)}' |sort |uniq -c`

Comment: or ... `grep -Eo '^.{6}' file  | sort | uniq -cd`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '
 {a[substr($0,1,6)]++} 
 END {for (i in a) {if (a[i] > 1) printf "%s (%d)\n", i, a[i]}}
' file
111111 (2)
112114 (2)
```

Answer (score 2):

With some `uniq` implementations, you can do:

```
$ <file cut -c-6 | sort | uniq -cd
   2 111111
   2 112114
```

Not all implementations support combining `-c` (count) with `-d` (only output duplicates).

On those that don't, you can use `uniq -c` and pipe to `awk '$1 > 1'`, or [do the whole thing in `awk`](/a/405032) which will save you the sorting (but at the potential cost of using a lot of memory if there are a lot of unique strings (though here it's only up to 1 million different 6 character strings which is not a lot))