# find number of duplicated lines based on match before first comma

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed

How can I find duplicate lines based on the number before the first comma in the following data?

Input:

```
112112112,00,00,00
110110,01,01,02
112112112,11,11,888
110110,99,88,8
410410,22,22,22
```

Output:

```
112112112 (2)
110110    (2)
```

Comment: `cat file |awk  -F',' {print $1} |sort | uniq -cd`

Comment: @user3333911 you mistook the comment box for the answer box :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With single **`awk`**:

```
awk -F, '{ a[$1]++ }END{ for(i in a) if(a[i]>1) printf "%-12s(%d)\n",i,a[i] }' file
```

The output:

```
110110      (2)
112112112   (2)
```

Comment: in case if i would like to remove numbers before field one if they repeated with the original ?

Answer (score 1):

Although you could modify [steeldriver's solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/405032/117549) to your previous similar problem, here's a quick & dirty pipeline:

```
cut -d, -f1 < input | sort | uniq -c | awk '$1 > 1 { print $2, "(" $1 ")" }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Piping your input file into the following should do it:

```
cut -f1 -d, | sort | uniq -cd
```

The output is not the exact same as what you posted; the duplicate count is the first column, rather than last and parenthesized:

```
  2 110110
  2 112112112
```

The call to `cut` asks to isolate the first comma-separated field, `sort` ensures that identical fields will be in sequence, which is required for `uniq` to group those; `-c` asks to count and `-d` to only show duplicates. Sorting the entire input may not be the most efficient way to achieve what you are asking, but this should only be an issue if your input grows very large.